# dojo/query style("border-right", "2px solid #CCC") not working on IE8, but work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, dojo

```
dojo/query("td[class*=\"hello\"]").style("border-right", "2px solid #CCC")
```

I use this code to add `"2px solid #CCC"` to border-right of all TDs whose class attribute value contains "hello" 
the code cannot work in IE, but works in chrome and FF.

Already add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top by following advice, any replies will be appreciated.

Comment: How about doing it in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Do it on css. It's the better option I think.
I use JQuery for `$.post` and animation.

```
td{border-right:'2px solid #000000';}
```